# Dynamic DNS for IPv6 results in IP address could not be found

Tags: dns, ipv6, dyndns, noip

I am trying to switch my dynamic DNS from IPv4 to IPv6, but I am encountering a strange issue. The device is accessible via its raw IPv6 address, but whatever dynamic DNS server I use, it always results in an IP address not found issue. The IPv4 one works fine though. The server is also correctly configured, otherwise the raw address would not work.

What is even stranger is that services like http://ipv6-test.com seem to be able to verify that IPv6 functionality exists and also which web server I use. They also list the corresponding name servers.

I tried the dynamic DNS services of spdyn, dynv6, and ddnss. I also tried noip, but it seems they only support IPv4 for free. (My IPv4 one is with noip.)

Does anybody have some advice? I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your network is not supporting IPv6.